# can't re-launch LWUIT Application after calling destropApp() on Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2?

Tags: java-me, emulation, lwuit, lwuit-form, java-wireless-toolkit

I am using Sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2 and LWUIT for my j2me application.I have added one `Command` Exit. When pressing the `Exit Command`,i just calling `destroyApp(true);` It is successfully exited and then emulator shows the launching screen.Now,if I press launch again,my application do not open.So, is there any problem in my code?

Please Guide me get out of this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't **re-launch** after exit the LWUIT mobile Application in emulator. You need to run again for this. May be [this is a WTK bug.](http://java.net/jira/browse/LWUIT-84)